# Get all usernames from database to a list in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this controller:

```
public ActionResult NameSearch(SearchModel userSearch)
    {

          if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

              var db = new reviewlogsEntities();



              return View(db.logrecords.Where(m => m.username == userSearch.userName).ToList());

            }


        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");




    }
```

My question is the user that is currently searching for logs is looking for a username once they have a username they can output a list. The problem I am having right now is what would my requirements be if they don't enter a username. What should happen is all users and their logs should come up. I could just make an if statement that says if left empty just do

```
return View(db.logrecords.ToList());
```

I feel like there is another way I could do it without having to do that. Because my thought process is, what if the search needs to be more complex. Where they might not enter a username but they could enter a date they are looking specifically for, or vise versa. I couldn't really do if statements then without it being super messy. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework, by default `IQueryable<T>` is evaluated lazily, making them composable.  Thus, you can use multiple conditional statements to progressively introduce filters to the query.  Once done, simply evaluate the query by calling `ToList` (or enumerate the results and convert to models) and return the resulting collection to the view.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an if condition and do more filtering on the logrecords dbset as needed.

Assuming `db` is an object of your DbContext and `db.logrecords` is of type `DbSet<LogRecord>`

```
IQueryable<LogRecord> recordsDbSet = db.logrecords;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userSearch.UserName))
{
   recordsDbSet  = recordsDbSet.Where(m => m.username == userSearch.userName)
}
var resultList = recordsDbSet.ToList();
return View(resultList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create more search fields in the future, you will want to set up your query to accommodate that without refactoring. Here's is a common approach:

```
var searchResults = db.logresults.AsQueryable();

//User Name
if (userSearch.username != string.empty)
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(l => l.username == userSearch.username);

//From Date
if (userSearch.FromDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(l => l.CreatedDate >= userSearch.FromDate);

//To Date
if (userSearch.ToDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(l => l.CreatedDate <= userSearch.ToDate);

//Category (because logs always end up categorized)
if (userSearch.Category != LogCategories.All) //assuming enum here
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(l => l.Category == userSearch.Category);
```

Setting up your method like this is easy to follow and extend when new search criteria are added, and the resulting query only includes the parameters entered by the user.